# How do I display data from database table into Android TextView?

Tags: android, bundle, textview, sqlite

I'm working on application where user keys in his friends' personal details and save into SQLite Database. Then the user can view his friends' information in another page(activity). But when the user need to view his friend's info, it's not displayed in the 2nd activity. The information need to be retrieved from the database table. How do I do that?

Here are the codes - 
First activity -

```
public class PersonalInformation extends Activity
{
    EditText txtLikes, txtDislikes, txtType, txtDate;
    Button btnView, btnBack;
    Spinner nameSpinner;    

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    String friends[] = {"Kanak Priya", "Joanne Liew", "Melissa Haiting", "Michelle Lam", "Teo Kin Hua", "David Yeo", "Nur Ashiqin", "Stephanie"};

    final Context context = this;

    private int namesSpinnerId;        

    LikesDBAdapter likeDB = new LikesDBAdapter(this);
    DislikesDBAdapter dlikeDB = new DislikesDBAdapter(this);


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.info);

        nameSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.nameSpinner);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.spinner_text, friends);
        nameSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        /*BuddyDBAdapter buddyDB = new BuddyDBAdapter(this);
    //  buddyDB.open();

        Cursor friendsCursor = buddyDB.getAllNames();
        startManagingCursor(friendsCursor); 

        String[] from = new String[]{BuddyDBAdapter.KEY_NAME};
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.name};

        SimpleCursorAdapter friendsCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.spinner_text, friendsCursor, from, to);
        friendsCursorAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        nameSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.nameSpinner);
        nameSpinner.setAdapter(friendsCursorAdapter);
        //buddyDB.close();


        nameSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
            {
                 @Override
                 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id)
                 {
                     Cursor c = (Cursor)parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
                     namesSpinnerId = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(BuddyDBAdapter.KEY_ROWID));
                 }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
        //buddyDB.close();
*/      
        Button btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    likeDB.open();
                    long like_id;

                    nameSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.nameSpinner);
                    String NameValue = nameSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

                    txtLikes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtLikes);
                    String LikeValue = txtLikes.getText().toString();



                    like_id = likeDB.insertLikes(LikeValue, NameValue);
                    likeDB.close();

                    dlikeDB.open();
                    long dlike_id;

                    nameSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.nameSpinner);
                    String NamesValue = nameSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

                    txtDislikes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDislikes);
                    String DislikeValue = txtDislikes.getText().toString();

                    dlike_id = dlikeDB.insertDislikes(DislikeValue, NamesValue);
                    dlikeDB.close();

                    txtDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
                    txtType = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtType);                    
                    txtLikes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtLikes);
                    txtDislikes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDislikes);

                    if(txtDate.getText().toString().length() == 0 || txtType.getText().toString().length() == 0 || 
                            txtLikes.getText().toString().length() == 0 || txtDislikes.getText().toString().length() == 0)

                    {
                        txtDate.setError("Please key in the date");
                        txtType.setError("Please key in category");
                        txtLikes.setError("Please key in their likes");
                        txtDislikes.setError("Please key in their dislikes");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Your information is saved successfully! :D", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }                                                   
                }
            });

        btnBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMain);
        btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0)
                {
                    finish();

                }
            });

        btnView = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnView);
        btnView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    nameSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.nameSpinner);
                    EditText txtDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
                    EditText txtType = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtType);
                    EditText txtLikes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtLikes);
                    EditText txtDislikes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDislikes);

                    Intent i = new Intent(PersonalInformation.this, SavedInfo.class);                   
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putString("name", nameSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
                    b.putString("date", txtDate.getText().toString());
                    b.putString("category", txtType.getText().toString());
                    b.putString("likes", txtLikes.getText().toString());
                    b.putString("dislikes", txtDislikes.getText().toString());
                    i.putExtras(b);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });

        EditText txtDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
        txtDate.setHint("birthdate or wedding date");
        txtDate.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {
                new InputFilter() {

                    @Override
                    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start,
                            int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend)
                    {
                        if(source.equals(""))
                        {
                            return source;
                        }
                        if(source.toString().matches("[0-9 -]+"))
                        {
                            return source;
                        }
                        return "";
                    }

                }
            });

        EditText txtType = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtType);
        txtType.setHint("birthday or wedding");
        txtType.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {
                new InputFilter() {

                    @Override
                    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start,
                            int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend)
                    {
                        if(source.equals(""))
                        {
                            return source;
                        }
                        if(source.toString().matches("[birthday wedding Birthday Wedding BIRTHDAY WEDDING]+"))
                        {
                            return source;
                        }
                        return "";
                    }

                }
            });

        EditText txtLikes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtLikes);
        txtLikes.setHint("e.g. Skating, Photography separate by comma");
        txtLikes.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {
                new InputFilter() {

                    @Override
                    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start,
                            int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend)
                    {
                        if(source.equals(""))
                        {
                            return source;
                        }
                        if(source.toString().matches("[a-z A-Z -]+"))
                        {
                            return source;
                        }
                        return "";
                    }

                }
            });

        EditText txtDislikes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDislikes);
        txtDislikes.setHint("e.g. Skating, Photography separate by comma");
        txtDislikes.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {
                new InputFilter() {

                    @Override
                    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start,
                            int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend)
                    {
                        if(source.equals(""))
                        {
                            return source;
                        }
                        if(source.toString().matches("[a-z A-Z -]+"))
                        {
                            return source;
                        }
                        return "";
                    }

                }
            });


    }
}
```

2nd activity

```
public class SavedInfo extends Activity
{
    final Context context = this;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.saved_info);

        Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        String name = b.getString("name");
        String date = b.getString("date");
        String category = b.getString("category");
        String likes = b.getString("likes");
        String dislikes = b.getString("dislikes");

        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textName)).setText(name);
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textDate)).setText(date);
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textType)).setText(category);
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textLikes)).setText(likes);
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textDislikes)).setText(dislikes);

        Button btnEdit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEdit);
        btnEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    Intent backIntent = new Intent(context, PersonalInformation.class);
                    startActivity(backIntent);

                }
            });

        Button btnBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMain);
        btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    Intent menuIntent = new Intent(context, MainPage.class);
                    startActivity(menuIntent);
                }
            });
    }

}
```

Please help me how to retrieve data from database table into the 2nd activity as TextView
I'll appreciate any help provided. Thanks in advance! =)

Comment: arent you getting the data displayed in the second activity?

Comment: oh, I should've said that, after the user keys in his friend's details and view the info there are details displayed in the 2nd activity. But if the user goes back to 1st activity and choose his same friend and view the info he keyed in, the data is not there plus it should be displayed from the database table. let me know if you understand or dont understand what i mean. thanks

Comment: are you getting any warning/error in the logcat the second time?

Comment: there is  no error or warning in the LogCat. I didn't code in the 2nd activity in retrieving data from database table and I'm  not sure how to do it.

Comment: And, data should be retrieved from the database table where the data is inserted from the 1st activity

Comment: just to understand the question. step 1 : edit A1, save A1, show A2 works? step 2 : A2 -> A1, select friend, show A1 - new changes not shown? can you post the full A1 activity? i'm still not sure i got the essence of your question.

Comment: Calling finish on A2, will only call onResume on A1, not onCreate. Perhaps this might be of help.

Comment: @cosmincalistru in step 2, user selects same friend and check the same info but it's not there. and that same info should be from the database table(data insert from the 1st activity).

Comment: @cosmincalistru i've posted the full codes of 1st & 2nd activity

Comment: On `PersonalInformation` activity you are saving the elements to database but i don't see where you are filling them from database. Maybe that is the issue. How can they be filled if you don't fill them?

Comment: and, if `SavedInfo` activity is called only from `PersonalInformation` activity i would suggest that on your listener on btnEdit from 2nd activity to call finish() only, and not start a new activity.

Comment: oohh ok, but don't I need to code in 2nd activity in retrieving data from database table? plus in the 1st activity i just only need to insert data into database table

Comment: ok..can help me with what are the codes for getting the data from the table? because i'm not sure how to..thanks

Comment: you can follow this link where you can get data from the table http://codinglookseasy.blogspot.in/2012/08/sqlite-database.html

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, what you need, following is a code snippet to extract results from the SQLite database for a query. Hoping this will help you:

```
// Access Database to fetch info
try {
    newDB = myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    String query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE...... = ";
    Cursor c = newDB.rawQuery(query,null);

    if (c != null ) {
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Bean infoBean = new infoBean();
                infoBean.firstName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("firstName"));
                infoBean.lastName = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("lastName"));
                infoBean.id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("_id"));

                // Do something here to display information in TextView

            } while (c.moveToNext());
        } 
    }           
} catch (SQLiteException se) {
    Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not create or Open the database");
} 

myDbHelper.close();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. May I know what & why is Bean used for?

Comment: @MiyayayayaMi : Basically a java bean is just a standard

1) All properties private (use getters/setters)
2) A public no-argument constructor
3) Implements Serializable.

So there is basically no syntactic difference between a regular class and a java bean. A class defines a java bean if it follows the above standards.

Comment: oh right, it's a Java Bean. But it can be used in Android coding too?

Comment: Should I type in the codes in DBAdapter or in the 2nd activity?

Comment: Yes it can be used in Android. The classes defined using above standards allows libraries to programatically  do things with class instances that you would define using a predefined way. 

You should write the code in 2nd Activity and then setText for the TextView once you retrieve the values from the cursor.

Comment: @MiyayayayaMi : Please vote up / accept as answer if this was helpful.